# Encapsulates class library with Costura Fody

Tags: .net, dll, class-library, fody-costura

I have a .Net Framework `class library` project which includes other 3rd-party packages.
After I compile the project, all the dlls are in the output folder.

How can I embed the assemblies into the project's dll and get only **one single file**?

I tried with [Costura-Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Costura) but not succeed yet.

Comment: Please, share your code and what have you tried so far

Comment: https://github.com/kodaniel/Encapsulation

Comment: Works significantly better with [Costura 1.6.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Costura.Fody/1.6.2) but lua53.dll assembly still excluded. Maybe it's an unmanaged library and fody can't merge? And why the latter versions of costura do not work?